# How is $\int \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{2+x^2}}=\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{2+x^2}} + C$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was trying to solve [Ahmed's Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AhmedsIntegral.html) and it was required in one of the steps.

Comment: Set $x=\sqrt2\tan y$

Comment: You may just differentiate $\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{2+x^2}}$ to check it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something plus $x^2$ under a radical in an integral begs for a tangent substitution. Taking $x=\sqrt{2}\tan t$ works nicely, since then we have 
$$
2+x^2=2+2\tan^2t=2(\sec^2t)
$$
and 
$$
\mathrm dx=\sqrt{2}\sec^2t
$$
so now your integral is transformed into 
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{2}\sec^2t}{(1+2\tan^2t)(\sqrt{2}\sec t)}\mathrm dt\\
=\int\frac{\sec t}{1+2\tan^2t}\mathrm dt
$$
now multiply top and bottom by $\cos^2t$ to get rid of the scary $\tan^2t$ and find 
$$
\int\frac{\cos t}{\cos^2 t+2\sin^2 t}\mathrm dt
$$
and use $\cos^2 t=1-\sin^2 t$ to get 
$$
\int\frac{\cos t}{1+\sin^2 t}\mathrm dt
$$
and substitute $u=\sin t$, yielding 
$$
\arctan (\sin t)+c=\arctan
\left(\sin\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+c\\
=\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2+x^2}}\right)+c
$$
after playing the usual triangle games.

Answer (score 1):

Follow labs advice as it is most relevant. Using substitution $x =\sqrt{2} \tan y$ The integral converts to

$$\int\frac{\sec y \, dy}{\sec^2 y + \tan^2 y} 
=\int\frac{\cos y \, dy }{1+\sin^2 y}$$

which is $\arctan(\sin y)$

Answer (score 1):

Upon the substitution  u= x/((2+x^2)^(1/2)), the integrand transforms to du/(1+u^2).